# Why wasn't Ned Stark king instead of Robert Baratheon?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I haven't read the books yet, but my question is why wasn't Ned Stark king instead of Robert Baratheon? Was it because House Baratheon was more powerful than House Stark?

Comment: The question is, why would Ned take the throne? Why did Robert?

Comment: Because.. Robert Baratheon led the rebellion and Ned Stark was just some random (and not very powerful) lord?

Comment: Aerys demanded that Jon Arryn hand over Robert and Ned, who were his wards at the time. I wonder why Aerys wanted Robert in the first place, since it was Brandon Stark and his gang that had went to King's Landing and shouted for Rhaegar to come out and die. If Stark and Baratheon had been in open rebellion at that time, Rickard Stark would never have gone to King's Landing to "answer for his son's crimes".

Comment: Either way, Sean Bean would die

Comment: Sean Bean always dies. It's one of life's rules.

Comment: He made it out of Ronin alive...

Comment: He also survived *Jupiter Ascending*

Comment: I think Ned liked the simplicity of the North more than the lies of King's Landing.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Essentially Robert had the better claim.

The [Family Tree](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert_Baratheon#Family_Tree) here shows that his paternal grandmother was a Targaryen and thus his claim was solid.

In fact there are no significant marriages between the Starks and the Targaryens, so Ned had no "claim" to the throne. It's also abundantly clear that Ned did not want power for himself and had no interest in politics.

Comment: Additionally, it was Robert who started and led the rebellion.

More information here:
http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Robert's_Rebellion

Comment: "claim" doesn't really mean much when you win a rebellion.

Comment: @Kevin That's not entirely relevant though. The question isn't "Why was Robert king?", it's "Why was Robert king over Ned?". And Ned fought alongside Robert, and was even the first one to the iron throne (as seen in the Cersei quote below).

Comment: @Kevin - 'claim' is not everything after a rebellion, but its still very important. If your claim isn't solid it opens the door for others to raise objections and create their own rebellions. Just look at the War of the 5 Kings. Each felt they had a better claim.

Comment: @Kevin - The thing to keep in mind is that Robert's Rebellion was just that: a rebellion, not a revolution. The intent was to remove the king (and the Targaryen line), but no one was interested in overthrowing the Iron Throne. Sticking as closely as possible to the existing system -for example, by giving the Iron Throne to the person who would have had the strongest claim in that system- was a conciliatory gesture to the royalists, because it showed respect for the that system. This was likely instrumental in keeping the Seven Kingdoms stable, and Ned Stark would have respected that.

Comment: More accurately, Ned had no interest in or aptitude for *southern* politics. He was happy and effective as Lord of Winterfell.

Comment: @JBCP - technically, Robb and Balon didn't claim the Iron Throne during the War of Five Kings

Comment: In real life, rebels often put forward a plausible reason for claiming the throne. Have a look at the various English civil wars, especially the War of the Roses. Having a reasonable claim (in this case on the basis of family ties) would make it easier for you to garner support.

Comment: @3Doubloons - Fair enough, but Joffery and the Baratheon brothers did, and the point still stands.

Comment: @Moogle according to that page, Jon Arryn was the first person to call in his banners, which would make him the one to start the rebellion. That is interesting. I didnt know that.

Comment: But maybe I'm just reading that too literally.

Comment: I would say this is also because Robert was supposed to marry Lyanna while Ned simply wanted to avenge his brother's death.  Robert was also the better commander and lead the rebellion.

Answer (score 56):

Consider [this conversation](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Eddard_Stark#Quotes_by_Eddard) between Cersei and Ned Stark in [Chapter 45 of A Game of Thrones](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Game_of_Thrones-Chapter_45):

> The queen stood. "And what of my wrath, Lord Stark?" she asked softly. Her eyes searched his face. "You should have taken the realm for yourself. It was there for the taking. Jaime told me how you found him on the Iron Throne the day King's Landing fell, and made him yield it up. That was your moment. All you needed to do was climb those steps, and sit. Such a sad mistake."
>
> "I have made more mistakes than you can possibly imagine," Ned said, "but that was not one of them."
>
> <sup>A Game of Thrones, Eddard XII</sup>

Ned never wanted the Iron Throne for himself. Especially since, as Dan pointed out, Ned's good friend Robert had the better claim.

Comment: +1 for "Ned never wanted the Iron Throne for himself."  I think that's the most important reason.

Comment: After all, what's a throne or two among friends?

Comment: Yeah, look at how well it worked out for both of them.

Comment: Why is this answer **not** accepted?

Answer (score 4):

Lord Eddard Stark is/was an honorable man. He loved Robert as his brother much as he loved his flesh and blood. He fought side by side with Robert not for a kingdom but for Justice. The kingdom was secondary... Once justice was served, Eddard saw no need or want for the throne. He simply wanted to go back North with the remains of his family and offer them a proper burial among the dead below the castle of winterfell. Also, Eddard would have respected tradition and the fact that Robert had a claim to the throne... Eddard did not.

Comment: How did Robert have a claim to the throne? He won the rebellion and then he got the throne

Comment: His grandmother was a targarygen... remember.. when Eddard found Robert's bastard son Gengry, Eddard claim he had more claim to the throne than Joffery.. even though he was a bastard...

Comment: R+L = J is only a theory - even if a very compelling one - and you should acknowledge that accordingly. That said, what does Jon Snow have to do with Eddard's claiming/not claiming the throne? It's fairly irrelevant to the question in hand.

Comment: of course, you might be trying to say "Jon will make a claim for the throne because although he has Eddard's sense of honour and duty, he has a claim to the throne which Eddard did not". To which I would raise the counter-argument: Jon Snow turned down Stannis' offer to remove his bastard status and raise him to Lord of Winterfell, a position he had a strong and obvious claim to. What makes you think he would claim the Iron Throne and not Winterfell?

Comment: While I agree with this it is "sort of" a theory. You should have made that more clearer, but I think it is a good answer. Still I thought it was called "Ice and fire", because the Tangeryn's and Starks are fighting.

Comment: I think this answer explains things well, but other answers have sources, which makes them significantly better.

Answer (score 0):

Ned's sister was in love with Robert, and I suppose Aerys killed her. Then Ned's big brother Brandon asked for revenge, and he got also killed. So the Bareathons started war, not for being Targeryan, but for revenge and to end the injustice. Ned supported him because Robert was his best friend, and was fighting for his sister. The throne was not what he was looking for in his life, not even for Winterfell. He became Lord of Winterfell just because his older brother died.

Comment: The war started because Rhaegar kidnapped Lyanna (Ned's little sister)

Comment: Right, and Ned's sister died *after* the rebellion, not before it...

Comment: Robert was in love with Ned's sister. There's no actual evidence for the other way around.

Comment: This reads more like a fanfic.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's also fair to presume that he had the smaller army. Even if he tried, logically he'd be squashed in defying Robert's forces.

Comment: Robert and Ned fought as one. Not as rivals

Comment: I didn't say otherwise.